# elasticsearch how to save likes for a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for the best practise for recording 'likes' of an item.

If I have a document

```
{
  'name' : 'Dave',
  'age' : 40,
  'album' : 'foo'
}
```

If people decide to 'like' 'Daves' album 'foo'. Where is the best place to store these 'likes'? in the document?

```
{
  'name' : 'Dave',
  'age' : 40,
  'album' : 'foo',
  'likes' : {
   'user1',
   'user2',
  }
}
```

Or store the likes in a different type? Because When I return results for albums, Dave's album should rank higher because that album has more likes. But also I want to show how many likes the album has. But with people liking and un-liking albums, I want to avoid conflicts with updates.

So what is the best approach? Should I put everything into a queue? How will I query and arrange by number of likes if the documents are separated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement i would suggest you to store number of likes it in different type with album_id in each. Basically it would help you aggregate on number of likes per album.